# How to get a value outside of a .then()

Tags: flutter, async-await

I need to check a value of a variable set inside of a .then function so that I can return different widget, but I can't figure out.
Outside of then, the exists value is false, also if inside of the then it is true.
Also if I put the return inside of the .then, return is null.
Can you please help me?

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     bool exists;

      seEsiste(db, idPaz).then((value) => {
       exists = value

    });

      if (exists) {
         return Text("load Text");
      }else {
           return ZefyrScaffold(
            child: ZefyrEditor(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              controller: _controller,
              focusNode: _focusNode,
            ),
          );       
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: In my experience - simply make everything down the bottom async and put await at the call while returning the part before the `.then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just fixed using a FutureBuilder

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


   // var refertoRef = await Firestore.instance.collection("referto").document(idPaz).get();

    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: seEsiste(db, idPaz),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasData){      
           if (snapshot.data)     {
            return Text("spetta un attimo");
           }else {
           return ZefyrScaffold(
            child: ZefyrEditor(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              controller: _controller,
              focusNode: _focusNode,
            ),
          );       

           }

        } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      }

    );
```

Answer (score 0):

you should your widget to StatefullWidget and change your code to something like this:

```
bool exists;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  seEsiste(db, idPaz).then((value) => {
   setState((){
     exists = value
   }
  });
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      if (exists) {
         return Text("load Text");
      }else {
           return ZefyrScaffold(
            child: ZefyrEditor(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              controller: _controller,
              focusNode: _focusNode,
            ),
          );       
      }

}
```